# Passing anonymous function to method

Tags: matlab, class, oop, global-variables, anonymous-function

***testcalss.m***:

```
classdef testclass
    properties(Access = public)
        a;
        F;
    end
    methods(Access = public)
        function this = testclass()            
            if (1 == 1)
                this.F = eval('@(x)a * x');
                eval('this.a = 5');
            end
        end
        function Calculate(this)
            a = this.a;
            this.F(1);
        end
    end
end
```

***test1.m***:

```
global solver;
solver = testclass();
solver.Calculate();
```

I execute test and after it I get such message:

***Undefined function or variable 'a'.
Error in testclass/testclass/@(x)a*x
Error in testclass/Calculate (line 18)
            this.F(1);
Error in test1 (line 3)
solver.Calculate();***

Comment: Did you write a Constructor? Are you sure the `this` syntax works on MATLAB?

Comment: Yes, this syntax works. There is a Constructor. You can do it such: `global solver; a = solver.a; b = solver.b; c = solver.c`. Before it, when I create my class, I write a line `global solver; solver = Parabolic();`.

Comment: Can you edit that into your question? And also, could provide something runnable?

Comment: @lhcgeneva I fix my post. Please, look again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem related to the workspace the anonymous function is using. Also refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285725/passing-and-saving-anonymous-function-in-matlab). This should work:

```
 classdef testclass
    properties(Access = public)
        a;
        F;
    end
    methods(Access = public)
        function this = testclass()            
            if (1 == 1)
                this.F = '@(x)a * x';
                this.a = 5;
            end
        end
        function Calculate(this)
            a = this.a;
            f = eval(this.F);
            f(1)
        end
    end
end
```

Essentially you locally make a new anonymous function using eval, because you can't pass anonymous functions with fix parameters (like a) around like this, at least as far as I am aware of.